# Operational amplifier circuit, but one of Kirchoff laws doesn't work

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

In this circuit i have to obtain all the voltages and intensities assuming the operational amplifiers are ideal, but I'm having trouble.

I've found the voltage on the point right in front of the plus entry of the first opamp (\$v_1=9/23\$V). The voltage at the black dots is 0 for both, the voltage that comes out of the first opamp is \$v_1\$ too, and the voltage that comes out of the second opamp is \$v_2=-63/23\$V.

Easy so far, but when i try to sum the intensities that go from \$v_1\$ to ground (through the 1k\$\Omega\$ and the 3k\$\Omega\$ resistors) and from \$v_2\$ to ground through the 4k\$\Omega\$ resistor, they don't add up to 0, which bugs me and my whole class. Can you help please?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The OP define where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are, in the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: KCL won't work if you don't use all actual current paths. The ones you don't see in that schematic are the positive and negative power supply.

Comment: Why should Kirchoff's laws not work? The last time I checked them, they worked perfectly.

Comment: @Bart: I didn't say they don't work; obviously they do. They don't (seem to) work if you apply them incorrectly by neglecting one or more current paths. The ones that are neglected are the connections to the power supply, which also carry current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 'hidden' ground connection within each ideal op-amp for output current to return.  The output terminal of the ideal op-amp is connected 'internally' to an ideal controlled voltage source.  The other terminal of this source is grounded.

For example:

[image]

[Image Credit](http://publicism.info/science/electronics/9.html)

If you redraw the op-amp with this hidden connection, you should find that KCL at the 0 node holds.

---

I'll demonstrate the problem as I see it and the solution.  Consider this simple ideal op-amp non-inverting amplifier circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk3bOq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clearly, KCL does not hold at the 0 node.  There is no current through the battery since there is no current into either input. Since the output terminal is at 9V, there is 9mA of current 'down' through the load resistor RL.  There is no other ground symbol shown and so there is no current through the ground symbol.  Summing currents at the 0 node gives

$$9 \mathrm{mA} - 0 - 0 \ne 0$$

in contradiction of KCL.

However, if we explicitly show the *assumed* grounded terminal of the controlled voltage source in the ideal op-amp *model*, it's clear that there *is* 9mA leaving the 0 node and entering 'the bottom' of the controlled voltage source, exiting through the output terminal.  Summing the currents now yields

$$9 \mathrm{mA} - 0 - 9 \mathrm{mA} = 0$$

satisfying KCL.

Comment: Hmm. Opamp is ***ideal*** according to OP, so \$A_0=\infty\$. Just a note.

Comment: @jonk, I know and if you have an image without that irrelevant (for this problem) expression, feel free to edit it in.  At the Image Credit link, it is pointed out that \$A_0 = \infty\$ for the ideal case.

Comment: Instead, I just followed through the logic. What's needed is the current that the opamp supplies and the OP needs to know how to insert that and then solve for it.

Comment: @jonk, what is your intention?  The ideal opamp symbol hides a connection.  One could easily redraw the circuit using the controlled voltage source and then explicitly see the additional branch(es) connected to the 0 node.  This is the content of my answer.  Do you wish me to change it?

Comment: My comment wasn't intended for much. I'd read the OP's first salvo and had *not* read the OP's updates as I wrote something I thought might help. Just as I was posting it, I noticed that you'd commented to my comment about infinite gain but I still had not yet read the OP's updates. All I was doing was letting you know that I had thought it might help to add the current (because I'd imagined the OP missed that detail saying there was a KCL problem.) I hadn't intended that you change anything at all. I was just letting you know I'd pressed the add-answer button, is all. I see you've added more!

Comment: And I like that! +1

Comment: This is the correct explanation, but in practice it isn't very useful for analysing an *ideal* op amp circuit. It just says "the op amp contains a voltage source that provides the right amount of current to make the KCL correct at the earthed node". In other words, you add another variable to the problem (the voltage source) which you are not really interested in, and another equation (KCL) to solve for it. The practical approach is just to *ignore* KCL for the earthed node.

Comment: @alephzero, you don't add another variable to the problem since the voltage at the output terminal of the opamp *is* the voltage across the internal voltage source and further, you don't add another equation.  For example, in node voltage analysis, one doesn't do KCL for the zero node (the voltage is zero there by definition).  It's clear to me that the OP had already solved the circuit by the usual ideal op-amp methods but made the astute observation that KCL doesn't hold at the 0 node (not that it's needed to solve the circuit, just that something's funny with KCL there).

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear from your question what you mean by intensities or why these specific intensities should sum to zero. However, recall that op amps  an source as much current as necessary to satisfy KCL at any node. If there is an issue with KCL being violated at a node that includes the output terminal of an op amp but KVL and KCL are satisfied everywhere else, it is likely (necessary, even) that the op amp currents are being neglected.

Recall that the ideal op amp assumptions only assumes that currents into the +/- terminals are 0, but the current out of the output is unconstrained except to satisfy KCL.

Comment: I apologize for answering incompletely with an answer. I am one reputation point away from being able to comment on others posts.

Comment: have some rep then

Answer (score 1):

Your voltages \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ are correct. Assuming ideal op amps, the total (?) current to ground is

$$\frac{V_1-0.6V}{1k\Omega}+\frac{V_1}{3k\Omega}+\frac{V_2}{4k\Omega}=-0.763\;mA$$

According to KCL it should be zero. So, have we proved KCL wrong? No, we just made a mistake. We didn't take all current paths into account. The one we miss is the one via the power supply connection, which is not shown in the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the schematic (once you get your question migrated here, you can edit a schematic and add it like this):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhoxN3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So now let me point out your error. You forgot to include a current that comes from the output of \$OA_2\$ when considering your node, \$V_2\$. I'll include it below:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1}{R_2}+\frac{V_1}{R_4} &=\frac{600\:\textrm{mV}}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}\\\\
V_1&=\frac{600\:\textrm{mV}}{R_1}\cdot\bigg[R_1\:\vert\vert\: R_2\:\vert\vert \: R_4\bigg]=\frac{9}{23}\:\textrm{V}\tag{V1}\\\\
\frac{V_2}{R_5}+\frac{V_2}{R_6}&=\frac{V_3=0\:\textrm{V}}{R_5}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_6}+I_{OA_2}\\\\
V_2&=I_{OA_2}\cdot\bigg[R_5 \:\vert\vert\: R_6\bigg]\tag{V2}\\\\
\frac{V_3}{R_3}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}+\frac{V_3}{R_5}&=\frac{V_4=V_1}{R_3}+\frac{V_1}{R_4}+\frac{V_2}{R_5}\\\\
V_3&=\left(\frac{V_1}{R_3}+\frac{V_1}{R_4}+\frac{V_2}{R_5}\right)\cdot\bigg[R_3\:\vert\vert\: R_4\:\vert\vert \: R_5\bigg]=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{V3}
\end{align*}$$

By plugging equation \$V2\$ into equation \$V3\$, the above solves out as:

$$\begin{align*}I_{OA_2}&=-V_1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}+\frac{R_5}{R_4\cdot R_6}+\frac{R_5}{R_3\cdot R_6}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{9}{23}\:\textrm{V}\cdot 2.45\:\textrm{mS}\approx -958.7\:\mu\textrm{A}
\end{align*}$$

This current is what you missed out on. Because it is negative (and because of how I arranged the equations, earlier), it is being sunk by \$OA_2\$, out of node \$V_2\$. From this, you should find that \$V_2\approx -2.739\:\textrm{V}\$.

I haven't bothered simulating this, so it is worth your time verifying in your own mind that I've started with the right assumptions and followed it up with valid logic.

Comment: The OP stated that he found \$v_2\$ to be -63/23 V, which is the same as your value of -2.739. So I do not think that there's an error in the OP's calculations. Have you added the currents that go to ground? Do they add to zero? The actual reason why KCL doesn't seem to work is because the path to the power supply is not taken into account.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks. I started this prior to the OP adding that voltage (or my memory was wrong.) I guess I don't see that KCL isn't working. I just applied it above and have no conceptual problems. So perhaps I misunderstand the question. The currents do add up.